# Syncing Outlook Calendar Events to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Good morning everyone,

I am having a peculiar issue with syncing calendar events between outlook, my phone, and Google calendar.  I have been using Android Sync to import all of my outlook calendar events onto my phone and have not had any issues with syncing that way.  Android sync gives me the option to sync to a local calendar on my phone or to sync to my Google account.  Either way it appears that only a local sync is completed.  If I sync to my Google account, the calendar events show up on my phone, and are readable/editable, but as soon as Google calendar refreshes (usually via reload on PC) all of the events are removed from my phone.

I am trying to convert from using a local copy of my calendar to a shared copy so that other employees can have access to my schedule.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not being a Microsoft user: Does Outlook support *any* external calendar sources? In that case, maybe you can get it to work via an "intermediary".

Comment: There are ways to import calendars into outlook, and you can subscribe to a google calendar, but it is only one-way. A few years ago (circa 2012) Google had a direct sync between outlook and google calendar that allowed you to create and edit events in either and would automatically sync changes together, unfortunately they discontinued that.

Comment: There are several [results turning up for "outlook sync"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=outlook%20sync). [SyncRoid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/syncroid-outlook-sync-lite/com.gp.syncroid.lite) even has been updated this January. Worth a look I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, as an alternative:
An alternative to the google calendar outlook calendar sync issue is as follows:

1. Ensure that you export all outlook calendar into google calendar once only (ensure that you use your google calendar not the phone calendar for all appointments or change them so that they are)
2. Use google calendar to create and update all events
3. To then use outlook: export from google calendar and then import this calendar into a NEW outlook calendar
4. Rename the new calendar in Outlook to today's date (deleting or hiding other outlook calendars)
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 on a regular basis , deleting the out of date ones from outlook

Regards

Chris UK

Comment: This is essentially what I have ended up doing, it's unfortunate that I haven't been able to get an automatic way to do this sync, as I was previously able to automatically sync outlook to my phone. Oh well, a little elbow grease never hurt anyone!